# How do i setup a vpn server on a vps with only a ipv6 address?

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, ipv6, ipv4

I have a VPS but it only has a dedicated IPv6 address, i want to setup a VPN on it for me to connect to.

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 2):

Just as you would for a server that has an ipv4 address. The limitation is that only ipv6 clients can connect to that server.